# How to use smartctl with one raid controller

Tags: raid, smart, smartctl

I using a PERC H730 Mini raid controller :

```shell
# lspci -d::0104 -k
02:00.0 RAID bus controller: Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 [Invader] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Dell PERC H730 Mini
        Kernel driver in use: megaraid_sas
        Kernel modules: megaraid_sas
```

and here are the disks attached to the server :

```shell
# lsscsi -s
[0:2:0:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sda    499GB
[0:2:1:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdb   8.00TB
[0:2:2:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdc   8.00TB
[0:2:3:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdd   8.00TB
[0:2:4:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sde   8.00TB
[0:2:5:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdf   8.00TB
[0:2:6:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdg   8.00TB
[0:2:7:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdh   8.00TB
[0:2:8:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdi   8.00TB
[0:2:9:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdj   8.00TB
[0:2:10:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdk   8.00TB
[0:2:11:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdl   8.00TB
[0:2:12:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdp   8.00TB
[0:2:13:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdm   8.00TB
[0:2:14:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdn   8.00TB
[0:2:15:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdq   8.00TB
[0:2:16:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.28  /dev/sdo    399GB
```

On `smartctl`, I thought the device name was `denoting which disk on the controller is monitored.`

But then, when using one RAID controller `smartctl` also needs `The non-negative integer N (in the range of 0 to 127 inclusive) denotes which disk on the controller is monitored.` and gives a complete different result when the `N` value is different :

```shell
# smartctl -i /dev/sdq -d megaraid,0 -j | jq -r .model_name,.user_capacity.bytes
INTEL SSDSC2BX400G4R
400088457216
# smartctl -i /dev/sdq -d megaraid,1 -j | jq -r .model_name,.user_capacity.bytes
SEAGATE ST8000NM0075
8001563222016
```

It seems using `N=0` returns the wrong disk because the capacity does not match that of `lsscsi -s` output.

How to choose the right `N` value with `smartctl` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's normal. Your results will never match the `lsscsi` output, because the SCSI devices you see in `lsscsi` **are not** your physical disks at all – those are are the logical *RAID volumes*, virtual "disks" emulated by your RAID controller (which don't have any SMART data due to being virtual).

The actual physical disks are not visible to the OS – they're hidden "behind" the RAID controller (that's literally the controller's job), which is why you need the `-d megaraid` "cheat code" to access them.

(If the controller worked like an ordinary HBA and exposed the disks directly, you wouldn't need any special syntax to access them, you'd just use their /dev names; but then the controller couldn't really implement RAID without interference.)

Comment: @u1686-grawity If I understand what you wrote, then `/dev/sdq` is a virtual disk and `The non-negative integer N` stands for the position of one physical disk inside the `/dev/sdq` virtual disk RAID array, is that correct ?